# Why would the word "patriotic" have negative connotations?

Tags: connotation

In the Third Act of G. B. Shaw's play *Man and Superman* (a.k.a. *Don Juan in Hell*), the lead character castigates the devil's friends by changing what is conventionally taken as their flattering characteristic to derisive ones.

I wonder in what sense is the word *patriotic* being used when he juxtaposes it to *public-spirited*? What does it (the word *patriotic*) mean in this context?

Here's the monologue (the juxtaposition is in bold):

> DON JUAN. Pooh! why should I be civil to them or to you? In this
> Palace of Lies a truth or two will not hurt you. Your friends are all
> the dullest dogs I know. They are not beautiful: they are only
> decorated. They are not clean: they are only shaved and starched. They
> are not dignified: they are only fashionably dressed. They are not
> educated they are only college passmen. They are not religious: they
> are only pewrenters. They are not moral: they are only conventional.
> They are not virtuous: they are only cowardly. They are not even
> vicious: they are only "frail." They are not artistic: they are only
> lascivious. They are not prosperous: they are only rich. They are not
> loyal, they are only servile; not dutiful, only sheepish; **not public
> spirited, only patriotic;** not courageous, only quarrelsome; not
> determined, only obstinate; not masterful, only domineering; not
> self-controlled, only obtuse; not self-respecting, only vain; not
> kind, only sentimental; not social, only gregarious; not considerate,
> only polite; not intelligent, only opinionated; not progressive, only
> factious; not imaginative, only superstitious; not just, only
> vindictive; not generous, only propitiatory; not disciplined, only
> cowed; and not truthful at all—liars every one of them, to the very
> backbone of their souls.

Comment: Patriotism, it has been said, is the last refuge of the scoundrel.

Comment: Shaw is referring to phonies acting patriotic instead of actually being neighborly. Today, Shaw might say that virtue signaling is not virtuous any more than showing off your humility is humble.

Comment: It’s a nice exercise in nuance. Is a person cautious, or only easily frightened? Diverse in their interests, or unable to concentrate? Wary or paranoid?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I've been so advised, thank you.

Comment: Patriotism is associated with some very bad things, including uncritical praise and loyalty to your country (allowing it to get away with very bad behaviour), warmongering, and suppression of any kind of criticism or independent thought. See for example *Catch 22*, the Jan 6th invasion of the US Capitol and the entire 45th Presidency.

Comment: ***The dark side of patriotism***: https://www.boulderweekly.com/opinion/dark-side-patriotism/ - ***”Vigorous support for one’s country.”***

That is the simple definition of “patriotism” according to the dictionary. Patriotism, by definition, isn’t inherently good or bad. It all depends on what exactly is being vigorously supported.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - The expression 'virtue signaling' was concocted, and is mainly used, by right wingers to attack anyone expressing progressive views or ideas. It is a put-down that is past its sell-by date. As Shaw was a Fabian, I doubt he would have borrowed a taunt from the right wing, and as he was an Irishman, I think he would have spelt 'signalling' the British way.

Comment: @DJClayworth - "uncritical praise and loyalty to your country" I like GK Chesterton's dictum that "My country, right or wrong" is something no patriot would say, because it is equivalent to saying "My mother, drunk or sober".

Comment: Shaw reportedly said "Patriotism is your conviction that this country is superior to all other countries because you were born in it." (Although I'm failing to find an authoritative source.)

Comment: All the pairs contrast genuine virtues with illusory or fake versions of themselves, in keeping with Shaw's premise here that Heaven is a spiritual realm where life is real and life is earnest, Hell is the preferred milieu of those who prefer comfortable illusions, and the dead are at liberty to choose between them. Don Juan decamps for Heaven at the end of the dream sequence "Don Juan in Hell," which dominates but does not entirely fill Act III of *Man and Superman.*